Mathematica to Python
I have very large expressions in Mathematica which I need to convert to python for fast numerical computations. Is there a way to do it automatically. I dont want to type it manually. It will take me a day or two to do it.

see how-to-export-expression-in-mathematica-to-python

for fast numerical computations I had no idea that Python is faster than Mathematica for numerical computation? Is this something new in recent Python? I do not use Python myself much, but I have read it is on the slow end as a language.

Basically if you have loops involved over millions of points then you can use just in time compilation from numba to speed it up and it performs as well as C almost

You can use compilation in Mathematica as well. Translating arithmetic expressions with a bit of string find-and-replace (i.e. StringReplace) should be quick and easy. ^ goes to **, [...]goes to(...)and you can do a plainReplaceAll` on function names as needed.

Use AI tools, e.g., Github Copilot or ChatGPT are quite good in translating code.
And yes, using FunctionCompile is another possibility, but tedious ...

Indeed, ChatGPT is quite good at it. It will even handle 2D/3D plots using Matplotlib and array operations using NumPy.

Was Compile or FunctionCompile tried?
